# Connecting to a SQL server using watir web driver

Tags: ruby, sql-server, automation, rubygems, watir-webdriver

I need some help connecting to a SQL database held on a server to compare some values in watir webdriver. Not even sure where to start really. Is there any particular GEM i need to install

My database lives on server xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx, with a username and password

so I have 2 issues:

1) how do i connect to the server?

2) then how do i connect to database?

Comment: Watir is only a testing tool which sends HTTP requests and parses responses as HTML and then manipulates them. It cannot test database directly. You need to build a web application that responds with html, then use Watir test your web application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Aetherus has said in the comments, watir-webdriver is only an automation tool for web browsers.  It runs in ruby, which means that to get the values from the SQL database you can use any ruby gem you like.  A good suggestion would be TinyTDS - https://github.com/rails-sqlserver/tiny_tds.

Comment: Thanks il have a look into that